# How to fold a tree structure in racket?

Tags: tree, sum, racket, fold

I have a struct that can create a tree structure:

`(struct node (value left middle right))`

and another struct that defines a leaf node:

`(struct emptyNode ())`

How do I make a function that folds the tree into one value by summing the values together, starting with the left subtree, then middle, then right?

I was thinking of converting the tree into a list, with the order of the left subtree first, then middle, then right subtrees, and then doing a foldl on the list but am unsure on how to finish it, or if this is the right approach:

```
(define (treeToList tree)
  (cond
    [(node? tree) (append (node-left tree)) (treeToList (node-left tree))
                  (append (node-middle tree)) (treeToList (node-middle tree))
                  (append (node-right tree)) (treeToList (node-right tree))]
    [else ] ;do nothing, leaf node
    ))
```

Comment: There are 6 expressions in the first cond-answer. Are they meant to be combined into a single answer? If you don't combine them, it will throw the first 5 away and just return the last one

Comment: Another strange thing is you said you want to sum the values, but the code doesn't use the `node-value` field selector at all in the cond-answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, a nice way to do this is by using Racket's pattern matching.  As well as this it's also nice to use an agenda-based search so that the whole process is iterative.  So the function that does the summing is going to have three arguments:

- the current node;
- the current agenda of nodes it needs to look at;
- the running total;

And then it decides what to based on pattern matching these arguments, looping over the nodes and pushing & popping things from the agenda.

So given definitions of `node` and `empty-node`, and a sample tree made of them as follows:

```
(struct node (value left middle right))
(struct empty-node ())

(define sample-tree
  (node 1
        (node 2
              (empty-node)
              (node 3 (empty-node) (empty-node) (empty-node))
              (node -1
                    (node 1 (empty-node) (empty-node) (empty-node))
                    (empty-node)
                    (empty-node)))
        (node 10 (empty-node) (empty-node) (empty-node))
        (empty-node)))
```

We can write a function to sum the tree like this:

```
(define (sum-node-tree node-tree)
  (define/match (snt-loop thing agenda sum)
    [((empty-node) '() s)
     ;; an empty node, nothing on the agenda: we're done
     s]
    [((empty-node) (cons next more) s)
     ;; an empty node, but there is an agenda, so start on the next agenda
     ;; item
     (snt-loop next more s)]
    [((node (? number? v) l m r) a s)
     ;; a node with a value: sum the value into the total, push the middle
     ;; and right children onto the agenda, and start on the left child.
     (snt-loop l (list* m r a) (+ s v))]
    [(_ _ _)
     ;; something bad in the tree
     (error 'sum-node-tree "bogus tree")])
  (snt-loop node-tree '() 0))
```

then

```
> (sum-node-tree sample-tree)
16
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [data/lazytree](https://docs.racket-lang.org/lazytree/index.html) package for this, specifically the [tree-fold](https://docs.racket-lang.org/lazytree/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._data%2Flazytree..rkt%29._tree-fold%29%29) interface.

Using the tree example in [@tfb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61698211/323874) (named `sample-tree`), we first define a function to get the children of a node:

```
(define (node-children t)
  (list (node-left t)
        (node-middle t)
        (node-right t)))
```

Then use it to create the tree representation:

```
(require data/lazytree)
(define t (make-tree node-children
                     sample-tree
                     #:with-data node-value
                     #:empty-pred empty-node?))
```

And use tree-fold to get the result:

```
(tree-fold + t)
=> 16
```